# Implementing Java/Android's callback/listeners in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to create an Android app in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo that makes use of [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API. I used Java2OP to create the interfaces that I need. Some of these interfaces are for callback/listeners. For example [CameraDevice.StateCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback.html) which Java2OP has translated to this:

```
JCameraDevice_StateCallbackClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{3F5A7394-FD15-439C-9BFB-DF8D43F9F930}']
    {class} function _GetERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function _GetERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE: Integer; cdecl;
    {class} function init: JCameraDevice_StateCallback; cdecl;
    {class} property ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE: Integer read _GetERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE;
    {class} property ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED: Integer read _GetERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED;
    {class} property ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE: Integer read _GetERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE;
    {class} property ERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE: Integer read _GetERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE;
    {class} property ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE: Integer read _GetERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice$StateCallback')]
  JCameraDevice_StateCallback = interface(JObject)
    ['{3A3944F5-A71F-4CD6-98C6-04B8D65C3B52}']
    procedure onClosed(camera: JCameraDevice); cdecl;//Deprecated
    procedure onDisconnected(camera: JCameraDevice); cdecl;//Deprecated
    procedure onError(camera: JCameraDevice; error: Integer); cdecl;//Deprecated
    procedure onOpened(camera: JCameraDevice); cdecl;//Deprecated
  end;
  TJCameraDevice_StateCallback = class(TJavaGenericImport<JCameraDevice_StateCallbackClass, JCameraDevice_StateCallback>) end;
```

It is my understanding that I should combine `TJavaLocal` with the interface that I want to use as callback/listener (in this case `JCameraDevice_StateCallbackClass`). Here is what I have done:
unit CamDevStateCallback;

```
interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, android.hardware.camera2;

type
  TCamera2Event = procedure(camera: JCameraDevice) of object;
  TCamera2ErrorEvent = procedure(camera: JCameraDevice; error: Integer) of object;

  TCamDevStateCallback = class(TJavaLocal, JCameraDevice_StateCallback)

  protected
    FOnClosed: TCamera2Event;
    FOnDisconnected: TCamera2Event;
    FOnError: TCamera2ErrorEvent;
    FOnOpen: TCamera2Event;

  public
    procedure onClosed(camera: JCameraDevice); cdecl;
    procedure onDisconnected(camera: JCameraDevice); cdecl;
    procedure onError(camera: JCameraDevice; error: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure onOpened(camera: JCameraDevice); cdecl;
    class function CreateNew(aOnOpen, aOnClosed, aOnDisconnected: TCamera2Event; aOnError: TCamera2ErrorEvent): JCameraDevice_StateCallback;
    property OnCameraClosed: TCamera2Event read FOnClosed write FOnClosed;
    property OnCameraDisconnected: TCamera2Event read FOnDisconnected write FOnDisconnected;
    property OnCameraError: TCamera2ErrorEvent read FOnError write FOnError;
    property OnCameraOpen: TCamera2Event read FOnOpen write FOnOpen;
  end;

implementation

{ TCamDevStateCallback }

class function TCamDevStateCallback.CreateNew(aOnOpen, aOnClosed, aOnDisconnected: TCamera2Event;
  aOnError: TCamera2ErrorEvent): JCameraDevice_StateCallback;
var
  tmpObj: TCamDevStateCallback;
begin
  tmpObj := TCamDevStateCallback.Create;
  tmpObj.OnCameraClosed := aOnClosed;
  tmpObj.OnCameraDisconnected := aOnDisconnected;
  tmpObj.OnCameraError := aOnError;
  tmpObj.OnCameraOpen := aOnOpen;
  Result := TJCameraDevice_StateCallback.Wrap((tmpObj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
end;

procedure TCamDevStateCallback.onClosed(camera: JCameraDevice);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnClosed) then
    FOnClosed(camera);
end;

procedure TCamDevStateCallback.onDisconnected(camera: JCameraDevice);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnDisconnected) then
    FOnDisconnected(camera);
end;

procedure TCamDevStateCallback.onError(camera: JCameraDevice; error: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnError) then
    FOnError(camera, error);
end;

procedure TCamDevStateCallback.onOpened(camera: JCameraDevice);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnOpen) then
    FOnOpen(camera);
end;

end.
```

This code does not compile because it complains the `equals`, `toString` differ from previous declaration and `getClass`, `notify`, `notifyAll` and `wait` are missing.

***android.hardware.camera2.pas*** is created by Java2OP and contains the interface definition of `JCameraDevice_StateCallback` and more.

Comment: I don't see equals,toString in your code.

Comment: @RBA `equals` and `toString` are implemented by `TJavaLocal` which I am inheriting from.

Comment: You need to write Java code to create descendants of Java classes. I've already done this in this project: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Camera

Comment: @DaveNottage I have seen your code and it is very good. But I was hoping it can be done without another java code. If I am going to write Java, I might as well do the whole thing in Java. After all Camera2 API is Android only.

Comment: @Sam There is no way of doing it without some Java code. Why do the whole thing in Java if it's possible to do most of it in Delphi (as I have)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying problem here, as @DaveNottage has intimated, is that [`CameraDevice.StateCallback`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback.html) is not a Java listener interface, but a Java callback class (albeit an abstract class that in some ways is therefore like an interface, but isn't an interface).

Because it is not a Java interface it is *not* a candidate for implementing with `TJavaLocal` despite the fact that in Delphi it is *represented* by an interface (as all Java interfaces and classes are).

`TJavaLocal` is for implementing Java interfaces, typically listener interfaces. It does not provide a means to inherit from a Java class (even an abstract Java class).

The clue is that the important interface created by Java2OP inherits from `JObject` indicating that it is part of Java's [`Object`](https://d.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html)-based class hierarchy. A listener interface when imported inherits from `IJavaInstance`.

Delphi doesn't support inheriting from Android Java classes (in contrast to its iOS support where Delphi *does* support inheriting from Objective-C classes, thanks to Objective-C being a native system unlike Android's managed Java VM system)